# How to avoid doing processes on a given directory name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, loops, file-io, file-handling

I'm making a program that removes unauthorised files from a file directory or files older than a specific amount of months. The problem that I have is that I also need to avoid two Directories within the directory with specific names and I'm not sure how to do this with the current method I'm using.
Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT: Tried using similar code used while doing the same with files, not directories but the outcome was not the same

```
 Dim dir1 As DirectoryInfo() = dir2.GetDirectories().Where(Name = Name!.Contains(("(0000000.00A)" & "(0000000.00B)")))  'Makes reference to the directory in dir2
```

The code below is what I currently have running:

```
Dim dir2 As New DirectoryInfo("D:\Administrator\Desktop\File Directories\File Directories\00000000.00F")    
Dim dir1 As DirectoryInfo() = dir2.GetDirectories()

    Dim Auth(lstApprovedItems.Items.Count - 1) As String
    lstApprovedItems.Items.CopyTo(Auth, 0)

    Dim fri2 As DirectoryInfo
    For Each fri2 In dir1

        FileName1 = Convert.ToString(fri2.Name)     

        Dim dir0 As New DirectoryInfo("D:\Administrator\Desktop\File Directories\File Directories\00000000.00F\" + FileName1) 'Makes reference to a directory   ##### Needs to be changed to relevant directory #####
        Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = dir0.GetFiles()     'Gets reference to each file in the directory in the 'dir' variable

        For Each fi As FileInfo In dir0.GetFiles

            If Auth.Contains(fi.Extension) Then

                CreatedDate = fi.CreationTime
                DueDate = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, CreatedDate, CurrentDate) 

                If DueDate < 90 Then   

                    AuthList.Add(fi)

                Else       

             Dim MoveFile As String = "D:\Administrator\Desktop\File Directories\Archive\Archive 0.4\" + fi.ToString
                    NoAuthList.Add(fi)          'Adds the files to a no authorisation list
                    If File.Exists(MoveFile) Then      

                    Else           
                        fi.CopyTo(MoveFile)       
                        MovedFiles = MovedFiles + 1     
                    End If

                End If

            Else    

                 Dim MoveFile As String = "D:\Administrator\Desktop\File Directories\Archive\Archive 0.4\" + fi.ToString
                NoAuthList.Add(fi)          
                If File.Exists(MoveFile) Then       

                Else            
                    fi.CopyTo(MoveFile)             
                    MovedFiles = MovedFiles + 1                         End If

            End If
        Next

    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a Dictionary or Collection object that you can load from a config file and just check before delete that the file or directory is not in the collection. You are effectively making a white-list of what items should never be removed, which can be modified at any time by any admin that needs to protect particular files/directories. Since it is a white-list and only served to protect particular files/directories you lower the chance that someone could modify the file and add problematic entries. Though you should still sanitize the read of this file to ensure it follows proper formatting before trying to load the items into the collection.

You can create a function that reads in your file containing your list of files/directories. First you would edit your App.config file and add an entry like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- ... -->
    <add key="exemptListFile" value="C:\path\to\exemptfiles.txt"/>
    <!-- ... -->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then in the referenced text file add each entry, one per line:

```
C:\Some\Protected\Directory\
C:\Some\Protected\File.txt
```

Then add a new function somewhere in your project:

```
public Collection<string> GetExemptPaths()
{
    Collection<string> paths = new Collection<string>();
    string filePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exemptListFile"];
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) return paths;
    using(StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        while(!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string pathToAdd = reader.ReadLine();
            if (File.Exists(pathToAdd) || Directory.Exists(pathToAdd))
                paths.Add(pathToAdd);
        }
    }
    return paths;
}
```

Then simply call that function and assign the return Collection to a variable in your function:

```
Collection<string> excludePaths = GetExemptPaths();
```

And check that the file/directory you are about to delete is not in that collection.

Comment: I've never done anything regarding the config file. That sounds useful to another part of my program where I'm storing a list of 'text' into a text file but need to hide/lock it from other users but still have read/write capabilities. Care to give an example or reference?

Comment: Updated. Apologies, I forgot you originally had yours in VB.Net, the concept is the same though.

Comment: Thanks for your help, kind of helped answer my problem